# Can't assign a data value to a string - returns null - flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my code, am trying a assign a string value to an empty string and display on the page but it keeps showing null but when I print it out, it shows the value.

```
String fName = '';

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

getData() async {
    FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    User _firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser;
    print("============ MyHome ================");
    print(_firebaseUser.uid);
    _currentUser = await Database().getUserData(_firebaseUser.uid);
    if (_currentUser != null) {
      fName = _currentUser.firstName;
      print(_currentUser.firstName);
    } 
  }
```

**database**

```
Future<UserData> getUserData(String uid) async {
    UserData returnValue = UserData();

    try {
      DocumentSnapshot _docSnapshot =
          await _firestore.collection("users").doc(uid).get();
      returnValue.uid = uid;
      returnValue.firstName = _docSnapshot.data()["firstName"];
      returnValue.lastName = _docSnapshot.data()["lastName"];
      returnValue.userMail = _docSnapshot.data()["userMail"];
      returnValue.userType = _docSnapshot.data()["userType"];
      print("====================== on getData =============");
      print(returnValue.firstName);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }

    return returnValue;
  }
```

And whenever I try displaying the data it gives me `null`

```
Text("Hello, $fName"),
```

Please how do I do this or am I missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `setState` to rebuild the widget tree with the value:

```
setState(() { 
fName = _currentUser.firstName;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the getData function is async, flutter has already built the widget tree before getData finished. You'll now have to update the state using setstate.

```
setState(() {
   fName = _currentUser.firstName;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new state since we have made changes to the previous state (since your getData function is async.

```
setState(() {
   fName = _currentUser.firstName;
});
```